# Inclusions of $C^{k,\alpha}$ spaces

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

> When is $C^{k,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ a
>   subset of
>   $C^{k',\alpha'}(\bar{\Omega})$?

Gilbarg and Trudinger says that "for the domains of interest in this work the inclusion will hold whenever $k + \alpha < k' + \alpha'$". They then give one example of a cusped domain for which $C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$ is not a subset of $C^{\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$, but don't elaborate further. Have the inclusions been characterized precisely in the form of a necessary and sufficient condition?

Answer (score 6):

It should be clear from the definitions that the example given is roughly the only thing that can go wrong. In other words, it is when $C^1$ does not go into $C^{0,1}$. This difference is of course because $C^1$ only cares about the points that are, in some sense, infinitely close. Whereas $C^{0,1}$ can jump across boundaries, in some sense.

Perhaps an example would make it clear:

Let $\Omega_1$ be the half plane $x < 0$ Let $\Omega_2$ be the region $x > y^k$ for some positive integer $k$. Let $f(x,y) = y^2$ in $\Omega_2$ and $- y^2$ in $\Omega_1$. Then $f$ is clearly in $C^1(\bar{\Omega_1})$ and $C^1(\bar{\Omega_2})$. To check that it is in $C^1(\overline{\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2})$ it suffices to check that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f$ and $\nabla f$ agree with the limit is taken from inside $\Omega_1$ or $\Omega_2$. In this case, both functions vanish at the origin.

It is also very clear that $f\in C^{0,1}(\bar{\Omega_i})$ for $i = 1,2$ individually. But by the definition of the Holder norms, to compute the Holder constant of a point $z\in \Omega_2$ relative to $\Omega_1\cup \Omega2$, you have to take the sup over, say, all points within distance 1 of $z$, not just those points in $\Omega_2$. So if you take the sequence of points $(x_j,y_j) = (2j^{-k}, j^{-1})$. Note that $(x_j,y_j) \in \Omega_2$ and $(-x_j,y_j)\in \Omega^1$. The distance between them is $4j^{-k}$, while the difference of the value of the function $f$ is

$$ | f(x_j,y_j) - f(-x_j,y_j) | = 2 j^{-2} \not\leq 4 C j^{-k} $$

if $k > 2$. Just to re-iterate, the problem happens because "points between distinct regions in the set $\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2$ are allowed to get together too close too fast." And in fact this is the only possible way for things to break. Once you put a lower bound on the speed of approach of points in $\Omega_2$ to $\Omega_1$ along the boundary, you can use continuity of the first derivative implied by $C^1$ to control how fast the the difference between the function can grow in the two regions. For example, you can compute in the above example, that you have $C^{0,\alpha}$ for every $0 < \alpha < 2/k$  , while no inclusion is possible for $\alpha > 2/k$.

You may consider this to be a defect to the definitions. (Whether you put the defect with $C^1$ or $C^{0,1}$ is up to you.) It is clear that $\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$ is not a connected domain. So it is a bit funny that the Holder regularity at a point $x\in\Omega^2$ should depend on the values of $f$ in $\Omega_1$. On the other hand, the two domains do become tangent very fast, so it is also a bit funny that the classical regularity should fail to factor that into the definition. Anyway, this naturally leads to the **external cone condition** for domains, which is what you should search for if you want to read more.

Comment: (Sorry about all the typos. For some reason MO is really slowing down my browser when I type in the text field. It's gotten bad enough to the point that I cannot reliably edit the text.)

Comment: The fact that in general $C^1_b(\Omega)\not\subset C^{0,1}(\Omega)$ is linked to the reason why hiking in mountain may be dangerous.

Comment: @Pietro: that's a wonderful quip. I have to remember that for when I teach a class on this. 

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $\Omega$ is nice enough, it's not hard to check that you have the following chain of inclusion:
$C^0(\bar \Omega) \supset C^{0,\alpha}(\bar \Omega) \supset C^{0,1}(\bar \Omega) \supset C^{1,0}(\bar \Omega) \supset C^{1,\alpha}(\bar \Omega) \supset C^{2,0}(\bar \Omega) \supset...$

Hence, to compare $C^{k,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$ to $C^{m,\beta}(\bar \Omega)$, you first compare $k$ to $m$.

If for example, $k>m$ then $C^{k,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)\subset C^{m,\beta}(\bar \Omega)$.

If $k=m$ then you compare $\alpha$ and $\beta$, if $\alpha \geq \beta$ then $C^{k,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)\subset C^{k,\beta}(\bar \Omega)$.

Obviously like Willie said, things can go wrong with crazy $\Omega$.

Furthermore, there exists a function in $C^{0,1}$ but not $C^{1,0}=C^1$.
We can take $f(x)=|x|$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ to see that fact.
You can also point out similar examples for other inclusions.

Eventually, you have the chain of strict inclusion, which gives you the the full characterization of $C^{k,\alpha}$.

Comment: @Willie: After writing, I saw my typos and edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add an – hopefully – interesting statement to give an example of how different the $C^k$ norms are from $C^{k,\alpha}$. While the first space is separable, the second space has incountable many elements $f_c$, that are pairwise more than 1 unit away from each other: $\|f_c - f_{c'}\| \geq 1$, forall $c \neq c'$.

Comment: and I forgot to mention, that $C^{k,\alpha}$ balls are pre-compact in $C^k$.